# Shell script question

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have below scenario and would like to know how to achieve

Run the shell script which has 2 commands, which should run sequentially. 
But the problem is when I run the first command, the prompt goes into the command that I executed and the second command never executes.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
ade useview testview
ade refreshview -latest
```

exit
~

Output:

```
[ ~/cron_scripts]$ ./test.sh 
ade:[ testview ] $
```

So when the command 1 enters a view then shell script loose control and never executes second command

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/359066/edit) your question to show us your actual script and what happens when you run it, and also what you wish happened?

Comment: Shell scripts should be able to trivially run one command, then another after the first one completes. That's actually the main case of what they do! There should not be any business of "shell script loose [sic] control". Please show your shell script and how you are running it.

Comment: I have edited the post, hopefully its better now

Comment: `bash <<< "ls"` runs bash “typing” in `ls`, however it does not keep the input open. May be someone can expand on it.

Comment: @ramesh did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Since the first command

```
ade useview testview
```

starts an interactive session, that session has to end before the next command in the script is run.

Once it ends, though, the script *will run* the second command. So it hasn't "lost control" completely, but is waiting for the interactive session of the first command to finish.

Comment: I want to run the second command in the interactive session. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: @ramesh Not knowing what `ade` is, I can't answer that properly. There may be, for example, some way of specifying a command for it to run, just as when one uses `bash -c ls` to start `bash` and instructing it to run `ls`.

Comment: Thanks, ade is just an example. It could be anything where the commands starts an interactive session and if we want to run some commands in that session. Just trying to see if that's a achievable case in unix scripting.

Comment: @ramesh It's definitely achievable, but it very much depends on how `ade` is operating. There's no general solution. Some interactive applications may read from standard input, other's from a file on the command line, and others, like `bash` will not enter interactive mode at all when given a command on the command line in the invoking shell session. You may want to look into using `expect`, but since my `expect`-fu is weak, I can't give a solution for that either.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda, when i run the ade command , it enters the view and still accepts all the unix commands normally.

Answer (score -1):

```
ade useview -exec /full/path/of/the/file/subshellcommands.sh view_name
```